# How do you remove obsolete publications in the Replication Monitor?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Through some bungling in creating and removing publications, I was left with a lot of obsolete publications which for some reason still remains in the Replication Monitor.

How do you remove these publications? It doesn't seem to have a clear way to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question of mine, but then again at least I found a way to resolve it.

I was able to remove the publications is by creating a new publication with the same name, then delete the publication again. This time the publication will no longer appear in the Replication Monitor. I did not remember if the publication has to be the same type as the obsoleted one, but it works.

**UPDATE:** Okay, the publication type and database name is important, otherwise the newly created publication will be considered as a different publication. Kinda obvious, but now I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative situation which I noticed on one of our servers occurs when a database with publications is taken offline. The publication then disappears from the object browser but is still shown in the replication monitor as per this question.

In this case, you can simply bring the database back online causing the publication to reappear. Then you can delete it and take the database back offline resolving the issue.

This will only work if the cause of the issue was an offline database though - I believe there are many other situations where this will happen though.